# Returning coordinates of a search string in PDF file in iPhone

Tags: ios, parsing, pdf, coordinates

I am working on iOS and I need to develop an app that searches for text in a PDF file and **returns the co-ordinate point of the search string**, so that annotations can be placed at that point.

Any ideas on how do I proceed?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325675/how-to-find-the-word-co-ordinate-using-cgpdfscanner-in-the-pdf-page-in-iphone/14292521#14292521