# PDF parsing to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, pdf

I'm working on a app where you can choose a pdf file. If you choose one, the app will speak the text for you (with text-to-speech).
The part of text-to-speech is working. if i send a NSString to the method.

Now i'm working on reading a pdf file. I want to parse the pdf file so i will get the information into a NSString. It can be a simple pdf (without pictures).

I have tried to parse the pdf file, but i didn't work. After that i looked on the internet but i didn't saw a complete sample code or tutorial for that. I have already tried it with the library information (http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html) but that doesn't work.

I'm new to Objective-C (but i know c and C++ etc.), so if it is possible i want little more that only a little hint to the solution.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: if you found some solution then let me know too

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325675/how-to-find-the-word-co-ordinate-using-cgpdfscanner-in-the-pdf-page-in-iphone/14292521#14292521

Answer (score 0):

I think [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) is a good sample code for PDF parser.

If you want to handle non-ASCII code,specially CJK(Chinese-Japanese-Korean)code, you also need knowledge about Adobe CID.

Basically you have to do followings.

1 Get a sample PDF parser code, like PDFKitten.

2 Write your call back function for Tj and TJ operator. In your call back function, you will get printable string.

3 You know rest of project.